# Embeded video displayed over html

Tags: html, embedded-video

Site which I am developing has a menu with drop downs, which is always on top and content is scrollable.

Some of content are embeded video from various sources, which appears over top navigation.
For youtube, we find solution by adding extra parameter: 
`<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />` which resolve this issue, but is it general solution or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that adding attribute to embeded tag and this parameter helps :). So, I need to add following changes to fix issue:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<embed wmode="opaque" ... />
```